# Why Is an Email Only Sent to Last Email Address in the Column?

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

In this script, I am trying to send an email to email addresses in range B2:B.  I have included my email address in the column to test it out.  I am getting an email as expected.  However, no one else is.

```
function sendReminderEmailTest() {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Send_Email");
  var range = sheet.getRange(2,2,sheet.getLastRow(),1);

  var emailAddress = range.getValues()
    .flat()           // convert a 2d array into a flat array
    .filter(String)   // remove empty elements from the array
    .pop();           // get the last element from the array

  
  var html_link = "<a href='something.com'> Site Name</a>";

  var html_body =  "Good morning,<br><br>"
                 + "This is just a reminder to check the " + html_link + " page to verify that today's attendance is up-to-date. <br>"
                 + "Thank you, <br>"
                 + "Management <br><br>"
                 + "<em>This email is an automated notification. Please do not reply.</em>"
  
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: emailAddress,
    subject: "Reminder",
    body: "",
    htmlBody: html_body,
    noReply: true
  });

  
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Is something wrong with the script or with permissions?  I have set up an installable trigger and the log indicates that the script was run without errors.

Update:  The email is only sent to the last email address in the column.  When I switched the data in the columns and moved my email up in the column, the email was sent to the last email address in the column.

Tried removing `pop()` from the code and got an error:  Invalid Email.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop pop returns the the last element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
function sendReminderEmailTest() {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Send_Email");
  var range = sheet.getRange(2,2,sheet.getLastRow()-1,1);//you were getting too many rows in this version of getRange the third  parameter is number of rows not the last row.

  var emailAddress = range.getValues()
    .flat()           // convert a 2d array into a flat array
    .join(',');       // join the emails with commas and now that you are getting the correct number of row you are not require to eliminate the last element in the array.

  
  var html_link = "<a href='something.com'> Site Name</a>";

  var html_body =  "Good morning,<br><br>"
                 + "This is just a reminder to check the " + html_link + " page to verify that today's attendance is up-to-date. <br>"
                 + "Thank you, <br>"
                 + "Management <br><br>"
                 + "<em>This email is an automated notification. Please do not reply.</em>"
  
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: emailAddress,
    subject: "Reminder",
    body: "",
    htmlBody: html_body,
    noReply: true
  });

  
}
```

I presummed that everything else worked

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
function sendReminderEmailTest() {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Send_Email");
  var range = sheet.getRange(2,2,sheet.getLastRow(),1);

  var emailAddress = range.getValues();
  let addresslist = String(emailAddress);
  addresslist.slice(0,-1);
  console.log(addresslist);
  
  var html_link = "<a href='something.com'> Site Name</a>";

  var html_body =  "Good morning,<br><br>"
                 + "This is just a reminder to check the " + html_link + " page to verify that today's attendance is up-to-date. <br>"
                 + "Thank you, <br>"
                 + "Management <br><br>"
                 + "<em>This email is an automated notification. Please do not reply.</em>"
  
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: ""+emailAddress+"",
    subject: "Reminder",
    body: "",
    htmlBody: html_body,
    noReply: true
  });

  
}
```

**Modifications:**

Changed this:

```
var emailAddress = range.getValues()
    .flat()           // convert a 2d array into a flat array
    .filter(String)   // remove empty elements from the array
    .pop();           // get the last element from the array
```

To this:

```
  var emailAddress = range.getValues();
  let addresslist = String(emailAddress);
  addresslist.slice(0,-1);
```

The reason is that your previous code only outputs the last element of the array. MailApp accepts multiple email addresses as long as it is comma-separated and in string format.

That is why I changed this:

```
MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: emailAddress,
    subject: "Reminder",
    body: "",
    htmlBody: html_body,
    noReply: true
  });
```

To this:

```
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: ""+emailAddress+"",
    subject: "Reminder",
    body: "",
    htmlBody: html_body,
    noReply: true
  });
```

References:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

Comment: Seeing email address comma-separated in the log, but no emails went through.

Comment: Any particular error generated on your end? Tested it again and it works well for me

Comment: It seems to be working now.  Cooper's code seems to be a little more concise, however.